# Subtract data using id in 1 column

Tags: r

I have 3 data set. All of them has 1 column called `ID`. I would like to list out each `ID` for whole 3 tables (I'm not sure I'm explaining right). For example

`df1`

```
ID  age
1   34
2   33
5   34
7   35
43  32
76  33
```

`df2`

```
ID  height
1   178
2   176
5   166
7   159
43  180
76  178
```

`df3`

```
ID  class   type
1   a   1
2   b   1
5   a   2
7   b   3
43  b   2
76  a   3
```

I would like to have an output which looks like this

```
ID = 1      

df1 age 
    34  
df2 height  
    178 
df3 class   type
    a   1

ID = 2      

df1 age 
    33  
df2 height  
    176 
df3 class   type
    b   1
```

I wrote a script

```
listing <- function(x) {
  for(i in 1:n) {
     data <- print(x[x$ID == 'i', ])
      print(data)
  }
  return(data)
}
```

why am I not getting the output I wanted?

Comment: Try `merge(merge(df1, df2, by = "ID"), df3, by = "ID")`? From there, it's just a single data.frame. (You can also use `dplyr::left_join` and family.)

Comment: @r2evans  merge can solve a problem of 3 data set. if i have like >20 data set i can't go that way. moreover merge() can't be able to give me the format i wanted :(

Comment: @PNY you have not supplied an R format, you have only shown the look.

Comment: Your question said *"I have 3 data set"*, so is it weird/wrong that I provided a 3-dataset solution? Alright, how are they all stored, does something like `Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x, y, by="ID"), list(df1, df2, df3, ..., df42))` provide something a little more palatable? From there, printing the format you want should be trivial. Where is `n` defined? Why are you comparing an `ID` with the string `'i'` and not the value of `i`? Why are you returning `data` after you print it? How will you call `listing`? What do you expect? What do you get instead? Your function is nothing like the output.

Comment: @r2evans sorry for the unclear question. I would like to have a script that later on whenever i have more than 3 data set i'll be able to do solve the problem. When i used merge it combine all data set together whereas i would like them to be separated. one problem may arise when each data set may have 30 something columns. then when we use merge() it's gonna take a mile for the output haha. I'm not quite sure if i use the right function that's why i didnt get the output i expected (the layout of output is in my question.

Comment: @PNY, could you please either mark an answer as correct or comment that you're dismissing this question?

Comment: @r2evans My laptop has been in store to be fixed for 1 week that's why i couldnt use stackoverflow for these days . My apology for not responding to your comments :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hack. If you want/need to export to a word document, I strongly urge you to use something like R-Markdown (such as [RStudio](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com)) using `knitr` (and, behind the scenes, [`pandoc`](http://pandoc.org)). I'd encourage you to look at `knitr::kable`, for instance, as well as better looping structures for dealing with large numbers of datasets.

This hack can be improved considerably. But it gets you the output you want.

```
func <- function(...) {
  dfnames <- as.character(match.call()[-1])
  dfs <- setNames(list(...), dfnames)
  IDs <- unique(unlist(lapply(dfs, `[[`, "ID")))

  fmt <- paste("%", max(nchar(dfnames)), "s %s", sep = "")

  for (id in IDs) {
    cat(sprintf("ID = %d\n", id))
    for (nm in dfnames) {
      df <- dfs[[nm]][ dfs[[nm]]$ID == id, names(dfs[[nm]]) != "ID", drop =FALSE]
      cat(paste(sprintf(fmt, c(nm, ""),
                        capture.output(print(df, row.names = FALSE))),
                collapse = "\n"), "\n")
    }
  }
}
```

Execution. Though this is showing just two data.frames, you can provide an arbitrary number of data.frames (and in your preferred order) in the function arguments. It assumes you are providing them as direct variables and not subsetting within the function call ... you'll understand if you try it.

```
func(df1, df3)
# ID = 1
# df1  age
#       34 
# df3  class type
#          a    1 
# ID = 2
# df1  age
#       33 
# df3  class type
#          b    1 
# ID = 5
# df1  age
#       34 
# df3  class type
#          a    2 
# ID = 7
# df1  age
#       35 
# df3  class type
#          b    3 
# ID = 43
# df1  age
#       32 
# df3  class type
#          b    2 
# ID = 76
# df1  age
#       33 
# df3  class type
#          a    3
```

(Personally, I can't imagine providing output in this format, but I don't know your tastes or use-case. There are many many other ways to show data like this. Like:

```
Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x, y, by = "ID"), list(df1, df2, df3))
#   ID age height class type
# 1  1  34    178     a    1
# 2  2  33    176     b    1
# 3  5  34    166     a    2
# 4  7  35    159     b    3
# 5 43  32    180     b    2
# 6 76  33    178     a    3
```

It's much more concise. But, then again, I'm also assuming that you want to show them all at once instead of "show one, talk about it, then show another one, talk about it ...".)

Comment: that's beyond my expectation. Thank you a millions of millions of time.

Comment: But i'm trying to learn how to use R-Markdown. R2wd package is to complicated to me :(. Thanks a mil again :)

Comment: By "*it gave out `NULL`*", do you mean it *returned* `NULL`, or that it put `NULL` out on the console output?

Comment: yes it returned NULL. My apology for bad english :(

Comment: [`R2wd`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2wd/index.html) hasn't been updated in over 4 years, more reason to consider learning Rmarkdown. The website I gave above is worth a look, though I know it won't necessarily solve everything. Just modify the code to capture the string instead of giving it to `cat`; replacing the `for` loop with something like `sapply(IDs, function(id) { ... })` or even `paste(sapply(IDs, function(id) { ... }), collapse = "\n")` should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a `merge` by id ?

```
df_1 <- merge( df1, df2, by='ID')
df_fianl <- merge( df_1, df3, by='ID')
```

or by using

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(df1, df2)
```

Comment: merge can solve a problem of 3 data set. if i have like >20 data set i can't go that way. moreover merge() can't be able to give me the format i wanted :(

Comment: and i would like to get each ID listed separately as layout above :)

Comment: then probably you need to create the df as list of lists. And parse through the list

Comment: The output format you provided is not something R format output. However, I still believe merging them as a data frame or as lists gives you more control on the data for any manipulations. Good luck

Comment: yes i'm trying to export them as doc. file using R2wd package. but it's a another story >.<